# How to remove duplicated packages on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: apt, update-manager, 15.04

I am running Ubuntu 15.04 and i have duplicated sources the problem started when i upgraded from Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04 I have ignored it for some time but now it's making me worried.

Comment: What do you mean duplicated packages?! Are those packages installed? or you mean duplicated repos?

Comment: duplicated repos

Answer (score 0):

Open your `Ubuntu Software Center` Then go to menu:  **Edit > Software Sources > Other Software**

Or just run the command

```
 software-properties-gtk
```

Then move to `other software` tab

[image]

Select and Remove duplicate entries.